# Do scope readings scale to the map size in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

I'm not sure if its just my own perception or not, but while sniping in Battefield 3, it seems as though depending on the map, the scope measures a distance. In other words, in a small map, a scope dot is a smaller distance than one in a large map even though i am using the same gun. Does the scope scale or is it just my own mind tricking me?

EDIT: I wanted to add why I want to know. I relate the player size in scope to distance. So if a player is 1 dot tall, then i put them at 500m as an example. With that, i know i need to aim 1 dot above the player's head to get the head shot. Granted, these are all general numbers, its the basic concept. However, it feels if i try to apply that scale from say metro, to Caspian Border, it isn't the same. It feels that on Caspian, 1 dot is more like 600m instead of the 500m. So then i have to adjust the position of the scope.

Again, the numbers aren't accurate to the game but it illustrates my question better (I hope).

EDIT 2: Since there is some confusion on my question, I'll try to clarify it some more.

With a static weapon setup (i.e. L96 with a 12x scope)

Does 1 scope dot = (X)m on all maps

or

- 1 scope dot = (X)m on Caspian (standard size map)
- 1 scope dot = 1/2(X)m on Metro (small map)
- 1 scope dot = 2(X)m on Gulf of Oman (large map)

etc.

EDIT: Made table clearer.

Comment: Are you referring to the power of the scope? In terms of its magnification?

Comment: No. The gun itself is static, ie its an L96 with a 12x scope, the only variable is the map size.

Comment: I don't know if this is constructive question you posted... You want us to prove or find proof that 500m with the same magnification and rifle will be the same  spot on the scope after adjustment between metro and caspian?  Where on Metro are you going to be able to shoot that far? the Train tracks??  Looking for clarification

Comment: I don't know where you can shoot that far, but the farthest HS recorded in the Beta (on Metro) was like 630m, so it can be done. But what he's trying to do is equate player size with distance judging off of how big they look through the scope, and if the relationship varies from map to map

Comment: I just used those numbers as a base example. Obviously metro doesn't have a spot you can snipe for over 250m from. I used metro because its one of the smaller maps, if not the smallest map in the game. My question is just asking if the distances measured by the scope dots is the same on every map, or if the scope dots scale to the map size.

Comment: @SSumner - Wow, i didn't know there was a spot you could snipe that far from on metro. Also, your comment is exactly what i was trying to ask. :-)

Comment: I don't know if the relationship varies from map to map, but I think you can equate how tall they are with how far away they are. The engines that BF3 runs on are pretty lifelike, and I'm pretty sure this works.

Comment: And I want to say that distance would be about sniping from the attacker to defender spawns on Rush on the first set of M-Coms (outside) or maybe one of the train tunnels have a straight section that you can fire a long way away.

Comment: @SSumner - That is sort of the issue. I'm not sure if its just my perception but it seems that the size of the player through the scope at static distances is static through all the maps. The only thing that seems to change is the dot distance. Again, could be just my mind playing tricks on me.

Comment: @SSumner - I think the distance would have to be from the RU base, through the building, through the ticket stand, to behind the middle wall to the wall where the front escalators are coming into conquest site B. Thats probably the furthest shot in that map.

Answer (score 1):

I think the scope is not changing from map to map, as long as you are using the same rifle and same scope.

As to your concern about the inaccuracy in different maps, there are many factors that affect the accuracy, Distance, Altitude, Enemy moving speed, Player moving speed, Player under suppression, and so on.

You need to adjust your scope now and then based on a variety of factors, not only the distance (which for itself, I think can be reflected by the size of enemy in your scope).

Comment: You forgot the biggest factor which is different with each map: The Terrain. If your're shooting up a hill, you'll need to aim higher, the other way around you need to aim lower. So it very much depends on you personal height and the height of the enemy. You may add this to your answer :)